# DOM Tree Walker as an exercise[JS]

Tags: javascript, dom

Write a function called nextNode that can be used to walk through all the nodes of a DOM tree. The function should take a node as an argument, and return the next node in the tree. For example, the following loop would visit every node once, and only once:

```
 var node = document.body;
  do {
    node = nextNode(node);
  } while (node != null)
```

I think from DOM it's supposed to only use `firstChild, lastChild, previousSibling, nextSibling,` and `parentNode`.

Code below should be how i imagine it to work. The problem is with the childNodes, seems like it needs a for/while loop to work. But the loop needs to somehow remember the last childNodes position and add i+1 because of it's call in do/while loop. I don't know what condition to give there and i get infinite loops.

```
nextNode = function(node) {
  // for/while loop?
  if (node.childNodes) {
  }
  else if (node.nextSibling) {
    node = node.nextSibling;
  }
  else {
    node = node.parentNode.nextSibling;
  }
  return node;
};
```

Unless i'm completely wrong about it. Could someone elaborate or point me in the right direction?

Comment: No, you don't need to iterate child nodes. You just need to jump to the `.first[Element]Child`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
var nextNode = function(node, deeperDone) {
  return !node ? undefined
       : node.childNodes.length && !deeperDone ? node.childNodes[0]
       : node.nextSibling ? node.nextSibling
       : nextNode(node.parentNode, 1);
};
```

It uses recursion for backtracking through the parents, since the next node may be several levels up the hierarchy.

Here is a demo:

```js
var nextNode = function(node, deeperDone) {
  return !node ? undefined
       : node.childNodes.length && !deeperDone ? node.childNodes[0]
       : node.nextSibling ? node.nextSibling
       : nextNode(node.parentNode, 1);
};

for (var node = document.getElementById('a'); node; node = nextNode(node)) {
    if (node.id) console.log(node.id); // skip text nodes
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
   <div id="b"></div>
   <div id="c">
       <div id="d"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="e">
       <div id="f">
            <div id="g"></div>
            <div id="h"></div>
            <div id="i"></div>
       </div>
       <div id="j">
            <div id="k"></div>
            <div id="l"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="m"></div>
</div>
```

Although you asked for a function taking a node as argument, there is the [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker) object (which Orial referred to), which is a kind of cursor, on which you can call the [`nextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker/nextNode) method repeatedly to *walk* through nodes in this order. Note that at the start, before moving to the next, you'd want to do something with the [`root`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker/root) node as well, which you can (at the start) also access with the [`currentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker/currentNode) property:

```js
var walker = document.createTreeWalker(document.getElementById('a'), 
                                       NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT);
do {
    console.log(walker.currentNode.id); 
} while (walker.nextNode());
```

```html
<div id="a">
   <div id="b"></div>
   <div id="c">
       <div id="d"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="e">
       <div id="f">
            <div id="g"></div>
            <div id="h"></div>
            <div id="i"></div>
       </div>
       <div id="j">
            <div id="k"></div>
            <div id="l"></div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div id="m"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing tree walkers it's trivial with [createTreeWalker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker):

```js
function iterateAll() {
  return document.createTreeWalker(document);
}
var nodes = iterateAll(), node;
while(node = nodes.nextNode()) {
  console.log(node + '');
}
```